# How to insert timestamp data from a list to google sheets in python

Tags: python, google-sheets

Im trying to upload this list of timestamps to a column in google sheets but is not doing it. is there a specific way to load time data? 'time' is a list of dates and times in 
this format -'2019-13T15:00:00.000Z'.here is what i tried  :

```
 def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_service_name, api_version, *scopes):
    global service
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    #print(SCOPES)

    cred = None

    if os.path.exists('token_write.pickle'):
        with open('token_write.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secret_file, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_local_server()

        with open('token_write.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)

    try:
        service = build(api_service_name, api_version, credentials=cred)
        print(api_service_name, 'service created successfully')
        #return service
    except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    #return None
```

## change 'my_json_file.json' by your downloaded JSON file.

```
Create_Service('credentials.json', 'sheets', 'v4',['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'])

def Export_Data_To_Sheets():
    for i in range (0,len(time)):
        response_date = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
        spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID_input,
        valueInputOption='RAW',
        range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME,
        body=dict(
            majorDimension='ROWS',
            values=time[i]))
print('Sheet successfully Updated')

Export_Data_To_Sheets()
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for datetime.strptime

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

foo = '2019-05-13T15:00:00.000Z'
bar = datetime.strptime(foo, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

print(type(foo), foo)
print(type(bar), bar)
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'> 2019-05-13T15:00:00.000Z
<class 'datetime.datetime'> 2019-05-13 15:00:00
```

Also as a side note. Try to use the pep 8 standard.
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Makes code more easily maintainable and readable in the long run.
So instead of:

```
def Create_Service(...
```

Better use:

```
def create_service(...
```

You should not name the list "time". There is already a time module, which could cause confusion and bugs down the line. Better use something like "service_times" or something like that (plural).
And using "i" if you loop through it, is not generally wrong. But try to have your variables also represent the magnificence of why they are there.

You used:

```
for i in range (0,len(time)):
```

Better would be:

```
for service_time in service_times:
```

Comment: i did this and serialized it but its still not in the google sheet:                                         
  import datetime
  from datetime import datetime

  times_list=[]
  for i in range(0,len(time)):
       bar = datetime.strptime(time[i], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
       times_list.append(bar)                                                                                         thenthis

Comment: class DateTimeEncoder(JSONEncoder):                                                               
  def default(self, obj):                                                                                         
     if isinstance(obj, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime)):                     
       return obj.isoformat() 
 print(DateTimeEncoder().encode(times_list))                                     
 times_JSONData = json.dumps(times_list, indent=4, cls=DateTimeEncoder)

Comment: can you maybe edit your original post with the new code? And please check what the content of "times_JSONData" is after you serialized the datetime list. Thanks!